# Ionic page overflow no scroll

Tags: angular, ionic2

I'm using Ionic for the first time. I started a project based on the [ionic2-starter-tutorial](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tutorial)

It works great but I face one major issue. When I add too much content on a page (e.g. [item-details.html](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic2-starter-tutorial/blob/master/src/pages/item-details/item-details.html)) the page gets overflow and I can't scroll on it.
I tried to surround everything inside a `<ion-scroll scrollY="true"></ion-scroll>` [from the doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/scroll/Scroll/) without success also. Any idea what is happening ?

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle *ngIf="!selectedItem">
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>{{selectedItem}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>



<ion-slides pager>

  <ion-slide>
    <!-- Lot of contents -->
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <!-- Lot of contents -->
  </ion-slide>

  <ion-slide>
    <!-- Lot of contents -->
  </ion-slide>

</ion-slides>
```

I would like to be able to scroll fomr top to bottom to see all the content of the page and not only the content that can be display according to the window height.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from the [official GitHub repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/6301).

I assume the problem is because dynamic elements are added to the slides. Overriding the slide height did the trick :

```
ion-slides {
  height: auto;
}
```